# Trouble getting jquery to see JSON object returned from Django view

Tags: jquery, django, json

I have a form that allows the user to change account info in the database. On submit, the form calls a Django view, and submits to a hidden iframe. The view returns a JSON object.

The hidden iframe can see this object. In the Chrome viewer, I can see the fields I expect being written to the iframe.

The trouble comes with jQuery trying to access this data. The jQuery function never runs. The console log and the alert are never triggered. I need to be able to trigger the function with the data being returned from the django view.

This is the jQuery block in my template file.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js'>       
$('#hiframe').ready(function(){
    $.getJSON('{{url_root}}/userupdate/update/', function(data) {
        var parseddata = $.parseJSON(data);
        console.log(parseddata);
        alert(parseddata.UserId);
    });                            
});
</script>
```

Here is the iframe and the form in the template:

```
<iframe name='hiddeniframe' id='hiframe'  scrolling='no' frameborder='0' style='display:none'></iframe>

<form id="userUpdate" name="userUpdate" action="{{url_root}}/userupdate/update/" method="POST" target='hiddeniframe'>
```

Lastly, Here is the dictionary I'm returning from my view function:

```
json_data = {'UserId': user_name,
             'FirstName': user_fname, 
             'LastName': user_lname,
             'Status': user_status}

return HttpResponse(json.dumps(json_data), content_type='application/json')
```

Edit to post solution:

knbk gave me some excellent suggestions and I was able to use those to make this work. I removed the HTML form, and did the send and receive from the view with code below.

Adding my solution in case someone else runs into the same problem.

```
          $.ajax({
                url: "{{url_root}}/userupdate/update/",
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: data,
                success: function(dta){
                    jsonfromDB = dta[0];

                    if (jsonfromDB['ErrMsg'].length > 0) {
                        alert(jsonfromDB['ErrMsg'].join("\n"));
                    }

                    // This is true when we have updated the database.
                    if(jsonfromDB['UpdateStatus']) {

                        // Grab the User input
                        fname.val(jsonfromDB['FirstName']);
                        lname.val(jsonfromDB['LastName']);
                        stat.val(jsonfromDB['Status']);

                        // We want the user to know when success has happened.
                        alert('Your database update was sucessful.');
                    }
                },
                error: function(errdata){
                    jfDB = errdata[0];
                    if (jfDB['ErrMsg'].length > 0) {
                        alert(jfDB['ErrMsg'].join("\n"));
                    }
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few problems with your code.

First of all, you have your javascript code inside a `script` tag that has a `src` attribute. If you include javascript code in your html file, use a separate `script` tag without a `src` attribute. That's the reason why your code isn't executed and why you don't see anything in the console.

If you fix that, and the code in your form is as I think it is (with a submit button without an onclick or anything specified), you first send a POST request to the server with the right data, and then, when the request is finished and the JSON is loaded into your iframe as raw text, you send another JSON request to the same url, this time through a GET request, without containing any data, and somehow expect to get the same response as you get in your iframe.

Also, it's generally better to use the `{% url 'view_name' %} tag than to hard-code an url into your template.

What you should be doing, is to have a `button` or `submit` input with an onClick function attached. If you use a `submit` button, you need to [prevent the default action](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) and the view attached to your `action` url should handle default form submission. Your JSON method should then use a different url/django view that returns JSON data.

This onclick function should collect the data from the form, and use an AJAX request to post it to the server. As you are updating data on the server, the HTML standard recommends using a `POST` request. To do this, you need to use [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) instead of `$.getJSON()`.

Your javascript code should look somewhat like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $('#<submitbutton_id').onclick(function(event) {
  data = {
   UserId: $('#userid_field_id').val(),
   etc.
  }
  $.ajax("{% url 'update_user_ajax' %}", 
   { type: 'POST',
     dataType: 'json',
     data: data,
     success: function(data) {
      <parse the data>
     }
  event.preventDefault()
 })
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. 

I'm not new to programming, but I am new to web programming. A colleague pointed out the same <script> tag issue as well. That definitely made me spin my wheels for a good portion of today :/

You're right to assume that my form submission was just the vanilla HTML submit. 

I'll work on implementing your suggestions.

Comment: Thanks again for the suggestions. I implemented your suggestions and got everything to work out. I've edited my OP with my implementation of your solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the point of the hidden iframe is. You also don't state what the actual problem is.

However, it does appear that your jQuery code is not within `<script>...</script>` tags, which may well be the problem.

Comment: Sorry. Let me edit that. 

The hidden iframe is because I have several forms, (one for each user) and I want to update the page with what changed. I submit to the hidden iframe then use jQuery to update the row that changed.

I tried to boil down the problem to it's most basic.

Comment: I also added more of an explanation of what I need help figuring out.